# Синтаксическая ошибка в коде на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Такой вопрос: пишу бота в телеграм для прохождения квеста. Код написала, вроде всё верно, но командная строка винды ругается на строчку:

```
bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "text2")
```

Текст ошибки такой: "invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma? ". Запятую нигде не забывала.

Сначала думала, ругается на пустые строки между кусками кода (хотя вроде не должно), убрала - не помогло. Подскажите, в чём тут мб дело? Вот полный кусок кода со строчкой, на которую ругается командная строка:

```
def get_text_messages(message):  
 
  
 
    if message.text == "Привет":         
 
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "text1")  
 
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "text2")  
 
 
if message.text == "Вперёд!":  
 
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "text3")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отступы надо проверить

Comment: Вы используете двойные кавычки внутри двойных кавычек: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ4Yy.png Нужно или внешние на одинарные заменить, или внутренние обратным слешом заэкранировать, либо внешние на тройные `"""` заменить.

Comment: Ура, замена кавычек помогла. Спасибо!